# Algebra Explaning Question: It is given that $21x + 6y = k$ and $(7x - 20)^2 + (6y + 10)^2 = 200$

Tags: linear-algebra

It is given that $21x + 6y = k$ and $(7x - 20)^2 + (6y + 10)^2 = 200$

ii) If $k=1$, explain how you could tell that there are no solutions without actually solving the equations.

iii)Explain why there cannot be more than $2$ solutions for all values of k.

I managed to solve the first part of the question but I am totally clueless about these 2 parts.

Appreciate if you could help:)

Comment: From the equation $21x+6y=k$ you can find an expression of $x$ or $y$ and then use this expression in the second equation. Eventually, you will get an equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$, which has at most two solutions.

Comment: Write 6y = k-21x for the second equation you will get a second order polynomial. Part 2 is a special case of the Fundemental Theorem of Algebra, where an nth order polynomial over R has exactly n complex roots (including multi-roots).

Comment: what kind of number is $k$?